# Htaccess doesn´t work - nice url

Tags: .htaccess, url, nice

Hi guys i have problem with a htaccess.

I want from this URL `domain.com/index?article=28&title=velky-biel-karlova-ves`
(it doesn´t have index.php because i hide .php extension with htaccess.

I wanna have this URL `domain.com/clanok/28/velky-biel-karlova-ves`

I used this code

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^clanok/([\d]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?article=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

My index.php file:

```
<a href="index.php?article=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>&title=<?php     echo createSlug($row['title']); ?>" title="">
```

It doesn´t work.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this you still have to mention index.php your php hide rule is different from this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^clanok/([\d]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?article=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Please ensure this rule is not conflicting with your existing rules.

Comment: what is the error/prolem also provide your current `.htaccess`.

Comment: Ok i changed my question.

Comment: Okay what happen if you try this url `domain.com/clanok/28/velky-biel-karlova-ves` in your browser?

Comment: [link](http://www.stovelkybiel.eu/clanok/28/velky-biel-a-15-3-k-ves-f) it´s working, but if i click on article (on index page) its redirect me to this link [link](http://www.stovelkybiel.eu/index.php?article=28&title=velky-biel-a-15-3-k-ves-f)

Comment: You have to change your links in your anchor tags with new link which we created.